# Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found error in PHP

Tags: cmd, stripe-payments, composer-php

I installed **laravel** and **composer** and created my first project in laravel. I want to integrate **stripe** using PHP. When I try to execute my first project in `localhost` I take this message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\stripe\public\elda.php on line 21

To include the stripe libraries, I inserted inside the `composer.json` file the code from the API library for PHP. Here is an image of my `composer.json` file:

[image: image of my composer.json file]

I run composer install in `cmd` and this is the output:

> You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.

I run composer update and the output is the error in the image below:

[image: erro]

Can someone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Please replace images with the actual text of file and output

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich i edited it.

Comment: Did you run `composer install` in the folder that contains the `composer.json` file?

Comment: @ floatingLomas Yess I did!

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry did not make a comment of your post, but I have not enough points to do so. But you need to run `composer install` in the terminal after that includes a new package.

Comment: Ok, I guess you are duplicating the key 'require' in the composer.json. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but when I ran this command my issue is resolved.

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

I hope this may help you, after you update your composer.